# Word to describe a real computer versus a virtual machine

Tags: word-choice

In computing environments a lot of software and processes are moving to VMs or virtual machines.  I am always at a loss as to how to refer to a real, physical computer in comparison to a virtual environment.  For example,

> Our amazing software can be installed on a VM (virtual machine) or on a *real computer*.
>
> Our amazing software can be installed on a VM (virtual machine) or on a *physical machine*.

Is there a better word choice to refer to a real, physical computer particularly in contrast to a VMWare or XenServer virtual computer?

Comment: I could try to offer a different word, but instead I'll point out that your sentence contains a lot of unnecessary fluff. Software is installed within an operating system environment. If that operating system *happens* to be running on a virtual machine, then you have installed your software on a virtual machine. This is not something that you specifically choose to allow or disallow as a developer —the OS will dictate it.

Comment: Computers **are** virtual machines. Computers can do nothing without an OS, which is always a virtual machine. You talking hardware/software, or what?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the duplicate question.  I did not think to search in the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen **physical machine** and **physical server** both used extensively. I tend to think **physical server** is the most pleasant option.

*Real computer* is a bad choice as a VM is a real computer. It's just one that's virtualized.

Comment: I agree about 'real computer'. I feel 'real' is a vague word in computing.